# gigabyte 5600 xt wind oc rev2 clock core

Tags: graphics-card, bios, amd-radeon, overclocking

Does the Gigabyte 5600 XT WINDFORCE OC 6G (rev. 2.0) video card in the second revision have an increased clock core to 1750? or is it possible only on the version with three coolers

Answer (score 1):

Core clock is 1460MHz, with a boost clock of up to 1620Mhz as per https://www.gigabyte.com/uk/Graphics-Card/GV-R56XTWF2OC-6GD/sp#sp

[image]

The higher clock edition is an 'OC' (over-clocked) variant, only available on the Rev 2. version. https://www.gigabyte.com/uk/Graphics-Card/GV-R56XTGAMING-OC-6GD-rev-20#kf

Comment: Do you know which 5600 xt video cards got BIOS for 1750+ clock? (e.g. sapphire)

Comment: @skitalec - see edit above.

Comment: i mean other vendors

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off-topic. I am not going to prefer one vendor over another. I have a preference for certain brands, but I won't state that here. It's not in the scope of the question or answer.